# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' on rasa.com and tensorflow backend

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, spacy, rasa-nlu

I'm studying chatbot with rasa.com, apixu, api.slack. But at the time want to training data, even out errors like this.
Can you help me to solve this problem?

By the way I use anaconda3, python 3.6.

---

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3>python train_init.py

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py__init__.py:34: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.

from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters

Using TensorFlow backend.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_init.py", line 17, in 
    agent = Agent('weather_domain.yml', policies = [MemoizationPolicy(), KerasPolicy()])

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\agent.py", line 42, in **init**

```
self.domain = self._create_domain(domain)
```

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\agent.py", line 237, in _create_domain

```
return TemplateDomain.load(domain)
```

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\domain.py", line 435, in load

```
slots = cls.collect_slots(data.get("slots", {}))
```

File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\domain.py", line 479, in collect_slots

```
slot_class = Slot.resolve_by_type(slot_dict[slot_name].get("type"))
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `slot_dict[slot_name]` is `None`. Make sure it is not `None` but some object.
Here is the same error in a simplified way reflecting what happened in your scenario:

```
>>> d = {'key': None}
>>> d['key'].get('type')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```